# Antonym/Opposite of "Legend"

Tags: single-word-requests

I've tried looking into this, but mostly I just get "factual"  I'm looking for the opposite of a person who is a legend for doing good things.  What would the opposite of Odysseus be?  Kind of like for famous there's infamous.  What's a person who's a legend, but not for good reasons?  *Is* there a word for it?

Comment: _Legend_ is not linked to any moral opinion as to one's actions. _Legend_ mainly means that the story is (mostly) made up, but worth telling again and again. So, yes, the opposite would be _factual_. Odysseus is not a legend, _his story_ is a legend. Odysseus is a _hero_, if you want. Then again, many legends are about people doing evil or bad things (or simply stupid), think of the story of king Midas (a legend about a king who was punished for his greed).

Comment: Your question could use some clarification. Do you want famous or legendary? Real or not? Because the opposite of a legend, to my thinking, is a "nobody" kind of answer. As @oerkelens stated, lots of legendary characters are evil, stupid, or otherwise undeserving of a positive connotation of "legend".

Comment: @oerkelens: "Odysseus is not a legend, his story is a legend. "  Actually, in AmE, we often say things like "He was a legend in his own time." or "He is a baseball legend".

Comment: @TimRomano indeed, but then _legend_ seems to be used as a synonym for _hero_ or _legendary person_, and it _has_ indeed a positive connotation. The antonyms that the OP found were for the _story_-meaning of legend, I may have read the question too narrowly.

Comment: @oerkelens: Yes, it's not clear what the OP is asking for :)  A noun?

Answer (score 2):

We can say

He was a *notorious* criminal.

or

Governor X was a politician *of great disrepute* in the 1930s.

Comment: I was also thinking of *notorious*.

Answer (score 0):

Rather too many questions here. Legend or myth, as a kind of account of events, is often opposed to *history,* which in this context is sometimes modified with *sober.* As for a *person’s* being a *legend,* the opposite would be a nobody or someone whose name is deservedly forgotten; thus, we cannot *name* an opposite to Odysseus in the sense of one who is as lacking in immortal fame as Odysseus is endowed with it. (In some other senses, we can indeed name opposites to him: his opposite in terms of his fondness for deception, for instance, is Achilles.) One who is known to fame for a bad thing or quality rather than a good one can be said to be a *by-word* for it (or *byword:* [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/byword) “someone or something that is closely connected with a particular quality”), as Timon for misanthropy, Thersites for obstreperous rudeness, Helen for calamity. Of course, one can be a by-word for a good thing, too, as Helen for beauty, and—depending on your point of view—Croesus for wealth.

Comment: And St Francis of Assisi for poverty -- again, depending your point of view.

Comment: @TimRomano: Or, perhaps better, *[Lazarus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=poor+as+Lazarus%2C+poor+as+St.+Francis&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3)* for poverty.